# IntelliJ IDEA FXML is not correctly recognized

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, fxml

Why does IntelliJ does not recognize all tags in this *.fxml document?
The JavaFX plugin is enabled and some of the tags are recognized... (I created this with SceneBuilder)

How to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't rely on the wildcard import for resolution of the `fx:root` type attribute.

Use:

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.GridPane" ...
```

Instead of:

```
<fx:root type="GridPane" ...
```

Then all of the node type specific tags (such as `<children>`) will resolve OK in the Idea editor and not be highlighted in red.

Do not ask me why this is so as I do not know.

I tested the above on [Idea 15 EAP ideaIU-143.116.4-custom-jdk-bundled.dmg](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+15+EAP), it may or may not work on earlier Idea editions.